Why does adding @MainActor fix my problem while the observer already runs on the main thread?
I've the following rough code structure:
struct MyApp: App {
    @State private var reconnecting = false

    private var showReconnectOverlay: Bool {
        return reconnecting //The actual code is more interesting of course
    }

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            if showReconnectOverlay { let _ = print("Blub") }

            SomeView(reconnecting: $reconnecting)
                .overlay {
                    if showReconnectOverlay { OverlayView() }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct SomeView: View {
    @Binding var reconnecting: Bool
    @State var device: MyDevice?

    var body: some View {
        AnotherView()
            .onChange(of: device?.connectionState) {
                reconnecting = device?.connectionState == .connecting
    }
}

@Observable
final class MyDevice {
    private(set) var connectionState = .disconnected

    func connect() async throws {
        connectionState = .connecting

        self.connectionTask = Task {}

        if try await self.connectionTask!.value {
            connectionState = .connected //This should remove the overlay from view
        } else {
            connectionState = .disconnected
        }        
    }
}

Now the problem is that the overlay is not always removed from view once the device is connected.
I can fix this by marking the connect() function with @MainActor, but I don't understand why that solves the problem.
I've added logging to all the functions and they show that the reconnecting variable gets set to false correctly, but the showReconnectOverlay function always returns true.
The logging also shows that the connect() function runs on a non-main thread (which is expected), but the onChange() handler runs on the main thread. So it seems SwiftUI already does some magic.
Given that the onChange() handler runs on the main thread already, what difference does it make to mark the connect() function with @MainActor?

You should show a [mre].

Just FYI, your edited question still does not include a [mre]. I should be able to copy and paste the code into a new project and reproduce the issue.

I'm trying to make a MRE, but that works just fine. So it's probably some side effect of other things going on in my app.

don't put your async funcs in classes, have them return a result instead.

@RemcoPoelstra – I would make sure the “Strict Concurrency Checking” build setting is set to “Complete”, because that excels at bringing thread-safety issues into stark relief. But, this general sort of problem can occur when the observed property is getting published on something other than the main thread, and isolating the method updating the published property to the main actor would resolve that (and isolate the published property to the main actor, too). But, we need a MRE.

@Rob That setting causes (maybe not by surprise) a lot of warnings. I've doubled checked that all code now runs on the main thread, but things are getting more confusing. I did al testing on the Mac, where the @MainActor trick works. But on iOS it has no effect. When I add an additional if-statement then the overlay is correctly shown and hidden on both iOS and Mac. Seems like there is some subtle issue in how SwiftUI handles the if-statement. I've added this line to the code in the question. Unfortunately, I'm still unable to produce a MRE to really find the root cause

I don’t know if it applies here, but I notice you are using a computed property (and that you have simplified this computed property for the sake of this question). But there are caveats when using computed properties with Observation if “the [computed] property that would be observed is not changed via some sort of composition of stored properties in the observable type.” That’s the only other thing that I can think of (in the absence of MRE)…

Re challenges in migrating the project, yeah, the first time you migrate to Swift concurrency with “Strict Concurrency Checking” of “Complete”, it can be daunting. If you haven’t seen them, Swift concurrency: Update a sample app and Migrate your app to Swift 6 are good resources. But tackle it piecemeal, module by module, and you’ll get there…

I replaced the computed property with just the reconnecting variable and the problem is still there. So that does not seem to be problem here. The 'MRE' that I've build is already half the application, so it's starting to loose its value and it still doesn't reproduce...
